# Paths to scripts in returned HTML file from action in MVC project are not correct

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC project and I am using SmartAdmin bootstrap template.

When I run my app and go directly:

```
http://localhost:8899/smartadmin/public/index.html
```

then everything works.

But when I return this file (index.html) in this way:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
      return new FilePathResult("~/smartadmin/public/index.html", "text/html");
  }
```

and run this action I have many errors in console. 
It looks like something with paths has changed because files couldn't be found
[image]

Paths should always start **smartadmin/public/**

This problem is also with other files, not only with styles, scripts. Even if I change these paths in index.html and run app, I will again have errors about other files (partial views etc).

I can't change path everywhere - it would be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you r using relative paths to you style files. The route to your action should have the same 'depth' as the html file that u use in the return of the action something like, /a/b/c. This is done in routing config in url param.
However, it is best practice to use absolute path in your view.

Comment: The problem is that I can't change paths. I have bought this template and it would be crazy to change every single path in scripts, styles, everywhere.

What I did -  I changed default routing to start /smartadmin/public.

So, instead of "localhost:8899" I have "localhost:8899/smartadmin/public" and then I return "index.html" and everything works. Maybe in final product I will just change name to make it something like /my-website/public.